# Variable undefined observable typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I had an issue here and I did someting but i would like to know if it's the good way to do it...

I have an interface:

```
export interface ContexteEnvironnement {
  langue: string;
  urlPing: string;
  urlFinSession: string;
  urlTimeout: string;
  urlRetour: string;
  urlBaseEpv: string;
}
```

I have a service:

```
contexteEnvironnement: ContexteEnvironnement;

getDataInitialisation(): Observable<ContexteEnvironnement> {
  return this.http.get<ContexteEnvironnement>(configUrl, headerGET);
}
```

And I have my app component where I want to get datas:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initialiserProprietes();
}

initialiserProprietes(): void {
  this._serviceConfigInitiale.getDataInitialisation().subscribe(data => {
    this._serviceConfigInitiale.dataInitialisation = data;
   this._langueService.setLangueCourante(data.contexteEnvironnement.langue);
  });
}
```

I had an error saying:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'urlBaseEpv' of undefined

So I decided to initialize my variable in my service:

```
contexteEnvironnement: ContexteEnvironnement = {
  langue: '',
  urlPing: '',
  urlFinSession: '',
  urlTimeout: '',
  urlRetour: '',
  urlBaseEpv: ''
};
```

And everything works. Is there a better way to do it ?

Thanks a lot for your advices!

Comment: when you use get<INTERFACE>(...) NOT want to say that you receive a response of type INTERFACE. You receive the response you get. The aim to use get of this way is for help you when you're writeing the code

Comment: If you get that error, it's not because `urlBaseEpv` is undefined, it means that the parent is undefined...

Comment: Where is this error thrown? You are not showing that essential part in your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use classes like this :

```
export class ContexteEnvironnement {
    langue = '';
    urlPing = '';
    urlFinSession = '';
    urlTimeout = '';
    urlRetour = '';
    urlBaseEpv = '';
}
```

and then write this in your service or any where else:

```
contexteEnvironnement = new ContexteEnvironnement();
```

Comment: Ok so in that case it's better to not use an interface ? Thanks.

Comment: yes . interface is used when u want to interact with an already created object  , not to create an object .

Comment: Can I still consider it as a model even if it's a class ?

Comment: yeah , why not ?